# Does php have a way of following database relationships

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table with relationships to other tables. Is there a function or method I can use in php to get a record from one table and follow the relationship with another to access a record in the second table?

Comment: You can uses "Join", "LEFT JOIN", "RIGHT JOIN"

Comment: This language agnostic. It's is [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins).

Comment: It's nothing to do with PHP. You would use SQL joins to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins If you are trying to fetch data from multiple tables at once.

```
"SELECT * FROM table_one JOIN table_two on table_one.id = table_two.xyz_column"
```